# Change opacity of images that weren't selected, but keep select image visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

basically when you select an image all the others change to 0.4 opacity, but the image I click on stays the same..

Here's my current code

This is just one of the images for an example, they are all the same, only difference is instead of the tennis wrap class it would be track-wrap (different wrap names for each wrap, other classes inside the wraps are the same).
``

```
   <div class="tennis-wrap map-markers-wrap">
        <div id="draggable1" class="location-imgs tennis ui-widget-content">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/lib/img/tennis.png" alt=""> 

            <div class="location-list">
                <h3>Sports and Wellbeing</h3>
                <ol>
                    <li><span>Willow Urban Retreat & Day Spa</span></li>
                    <li><span>Harold Holt Swim Centre</span></li>
                    <li><span>St James Valley Cricket Club</span></li>
                    <li><span>East Malvern Junior Football Club</span></li>
                    <li><span>East Malvern Tennis Club</span></li>
                    <li><span>Cabrini Health</span></li>
                </ol>
            </div>

            <div class="cross">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
                <path id="ic_add_24px" d="M19,13H13v6H11V13H5V11h6V5h2v6h6Z" transform="translate(-5 -5)"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>   
        <div class="location-pins">
            <div class="tennis-one location-number orange">1</div>
            <div class="tennis-two location-number orange">2</div>
            <div class="tennis-three location-number orange">3</div>
            <div class="tennis-four location-number orange">4</div>
            <div class="tennis-five location-number orange">5</div>
            <div class="tennis-six location-number orange">6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

``

```
 $(".map-markers-wrap").each(function () {
    var _this = $(this);

    _this.find(".cross").click(function () {
      var _this_cross = $(this);
      $(".location-list").hide();
      $(".location-pins").hide();

      $('img').not(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.4
      }, 300);
      $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1.0
      }, 300);

      setTimeout(function () {
        _this_cross.closest('.map-markers-wrap').find(".location-pins").show();
        _this_cross.closest('.map-markers-wrap').find(".location-list").show();

      }, 100)
    });
  });
```

From my understanding this code should check if image is not in this div, then it will change the opacity to 0.4, which it does, but it also changes the image that I click to 0.4 when it should be 1.0
Maybe I have a miss-understanding of the this keyword? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ```$('img').not(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.4
      }``` Should be **svg** I think.

Comment: the svg is just a little cross, this is clicked to display a list on-top of the image. The image itself is what should be changing opacity if its not the image that's been clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` is one of the divs, e.g. `<div class="tennis-wrap map-markers-wrap">`, so your call to `$(this).stop().animate(...)` will select the `<div>`, not the desired `<img>` inside the clicked `<div>`.

Try:

```
// Select all <img> tags not in this div:
$('.map-markers-wrap').not(_this).find('img').stop().animate({
  opacity: 0.4
}, 300);

// Select <img> tag in this div:
$(_this).find('img').stop().animate({
  opacity: 1.0
}, 300);
```

Where `_this` is each `.map-markers-wrap` div.

Comment: I added that code in, but still the opacity for all images including the one inside this, was changed to 0.4

Comment: Ok, I see `this` actually refers to the `.cross` element. Try changing `this` to `_this` in both places in my code.

Comment: That worked. So changing it to the _this variable meant that we're now searching inside .map-markers-wrap instead of .cross?